# Interrupts from LPT (bi-directional mode)

Tags: interrupt, lpt

I wish to ask You if it's possible to use ACK to generate interrupts (IRQ7/IRQ5) from ACK line (LPT mode set to bi-directional mode) ? I've set the mask bits of 8259, but still nothing. Interrupt procedure is not called. I am able to read data from LPT.

Answer (score 0):

You give no details about what you're trying to do, or how you're trying to do it.  Let me assume the following:

- You're on Linux ("lpt"?)
- You're using the standard OS's lpt driver (i.e. you've not written and installed your own kernel driver)
- You're writing some custom app that will talk to some custom device (who knows - perhaps even a printer device ;)) over the LPT port using a parallel cable
- You're writing this custom app in C (or some capable scripting language like Python or Perl)

If so, this link might be of help:

http://eagerfish.eu/lpt-programming-example-in-c-for-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: I'm using DOS (freedos) and I'm programming custom device (linefollower robot). I'm writing in Turbo C with assembler inserts. I'm forbidden from using custom libraries (system libs).